# How to find the xpath of a <td> that has no <label> tag inside of it

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have the following snippet of HTML,

```html
<tr valign="top">
    <td><label>Name</label></td>
    <td>FirstName LastName</td>
</tr>
```

I can find the xpath of the tr using `//tr[@valign='top']` and the xpath of both td's using `//tr[@valign='top']/td`. I want to craft a xpath that only works for td's that don't have a  tag inside of them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have done solved this using `//tr[@valign='top']/td[text()]`.

Comment: You can also use `//tr[@valign='top']/td[not(label)]`